# Model different product types with one or multiple sources?

Tags: anylogic, agent

I would like to build a model where I have six different product types. Can I do that using a single source and assign the product types upon exit of the source or do I need to use six different sources and connect them to a single queue?
On top of that, the different product types have individual probabilities. For example, product type A needs to be produced twice as often as product type B.

So far I've tried with a single source and two product types, but only found

`if (randomTrue (0.5)) xxx; else xxx;`

to be working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are a beginner, better use 6 independent sources, one for each product type.

Comment: In my opinion, Felipe is right in case you don't have to think about the order of your product types. But in case you try to have a specific order due to set-up costs (e.g. first all products of A and then B) it might be difficult to realize.